# Javascript callback function does't fire up

Tags: javascript, ajax

for some reason callback doesn't fire up. 
I cut all the extra code out, this is the structure. Perhaps i can't see something wrong here?

```
(function() {
  registerSecendStep = new Page('registerSecendStep', function(name) { //CLIKED THE BUTTON
    $('.register-second-step-button').click(function() {
      function doAjax(testReferral) {
        alert(testReferral); //THIS NEVER GETS PRINTED
      }

      showHint(function() { doAjax(testReferral); }); //START THE CALL
    });
  });

  function showHint(callback) { //CALLBACK
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert('called'); //THIS GETS ALERTED
        callback(true);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", helper.app.HomeSite + "/ajaxresponder?w=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
})();
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I did. Get 200 and state is 4 Just edited my code to show that.

Comment: You are passing `true` into your callback function, but your callback doesn't not have an argument on it, nor does it pass the passed in value on to the sub function.

Answer (score 1):

`testReferral` is never defined in the callback. Try:

```
showHint(function(testReferral) {doAjax(testReferral);});
```

Comment: @Alan, Walked in and solved it. Champ =) Thank You. I tried calling it so many different ways.